# Practices for hiding the executable code of compiled applications

Tags: c#, obfuscation, decompiling

It's a standard practice to decompile and reverse engineer .net assemblies.

I'd like to release some plugin assemblies that will add to existing applications, but I don't want them to be utilized by others.

What are some ways I can hide the source of these assemblies?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's theoretically impossible to achieve 100% protection unless you control the target hardware. If the CPU is able to execute it, given enough time and knowledge, a human being can read it too. This is not even limited to C# (although it's usually *easier* to do in managed languages). You can use an obfuscator like Dotfuscator or XenoCode to make it harder to understand the decompiled code. If you're really concerned, you should move to a server-based application.

Comment: Up to a certain degree a server-based application is reverse engineerable (if that's even a word) as well. Given enough time you can study its behavior and see every possible answer to every possible input, and eventually you'll be able to create another server-side application with the same exact **observable** behavior.

Answer (score 2):

You can use an [obfuscator tool](http://rustemsoft.com/freeware_obfuscator.htm), it will help but reverse engineering will still be very possible.

Your users' computer needs to know what it needs to do, so you have to tell it. The owner of the computer has total control over it, and can therefore know himself what you told the computer to do, and he can tell it to do something else.

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to hide the data, its called [steganography](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steganography). There's an author of a number of articles covered on [CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/security/steganoframework.aspx), who wrote a framework for doing exactly this. The title of the articles were 'Steganography ' in a series from 1 up to 12 I think. This is the [website](http://www.binary-universe.net/) that is affiliated with the author.

There is a also a obfuscator called 'Phoenix Protector', found [here](http://www.ntcore.com/), which can obfuscate the .NET code, personally, I have not tried it but it sounds good.

Hope this helps,
Best regards,
Tom.

Answer (score 0):

It's software; anything is possible.  You can encrypt your binaries, and then decrypt all or part of them into your application at runtime.  It's not foolproof, but it's up to you to decide how draconian you want to be.

Answer (score 0):

You can write an app that will [host CLR using the CLR COM api](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa964945.aspx), that way you can first load and decode the assembly at the native code level. If you reinforce the native loader using several [anti-reverse engeneering techniques](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/security/AntiReverseEngineering.aspx), you can achieve good enough security.

Answer (score 0):

At the very least, you should obfuscate your dlls to prevent hackers & competitors from viewing and making sense of your code. Obfuscation is not 100% foolproof, but it presents a big enough obstacle in their path.

Some obfuscators such as [Crypto Obfuscator](http://www.ssware.com/cryptoobfuscator/obfuscator-net.htm) have a feature of embedding all dlls in the main exe so your dlls are not explicitly visible and available on disk to open in reverse-engineering tools such as Reflector.